# Inserting an email address into a table field

Tags: email, mysql

```
// write student record
$query = "INSERT INTO Student (SLastName, SFirstName, SeMail, SGrade, SPhone, SCell, SLunch)".
" VALUES ($LastName, $FirstName, $email, $grade, $phone, $cell, $lunch)";
echo $query . '<br />';
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result)
     die("Error inserting Student record: ". mysql_error());
```

---

```
INSERT INTO Student (SLastName, SFirstName, SeMail, SGrade, SPhone, SCell, SLunch)
VALUES (Weiner, Wendy, somemail@gmail.com, 12, 2123334444, 8458765555, 5)
```

---

> Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@gmail.com, 12, 2123334444, 8458765555, 5)' at line 1

Server version: 5.0.91-community

Answer (score 8):

Shouldn't that be

```
INSERT INTO Student (SLastName, SFirstName, SeMail, SGrade, SPhone, SCell, SLunch)
VALUES (Weiner, Wendy, 'somemail@gmail.com', 12, 2123334444, 8458765555, 5)
```

i. e. with the email address in quotes?

Comment: You need to put the other strings in quotes too (although whoever downranked you was being a bit mean.)

Answer (score 3):

You are inviting a visit from [little Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/) by using user-supplied data unescaped in a SQL query.

Either use `mysql_real_escape_string` to defang the input, or use PDO to do it better.

Answer (score 1):

You need to encase your values in quotes:

`$query = "INSERT INTO Student (SLastName, SFirstName, SeMail, SGrade, SPhone, SCell, SLunch)". " VALUES ('$LastName','$FirstName','$email', '$grade', '$phone', '$cell', '$lunch')";`

Comment: Yeh, I'd like to know too. The other answer too, it seems a bit harsh.