# Python tkinter--ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000)

Tags: python, sql, tkinter

Following code is a function design for update data in mysql database.I get issue with following error message:

**Errors.ProgrammingError:** 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@gmail.com,gender=Female,

```
def update_data(self):
    con = mysql.connector.connect(
        host="localhost",
        user="root",
        password="123456",
        database="stm",
    )
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute(
        """
        update
            students
        set 
            name=%s,
            email=%s,
            gender=%s,
            contact=%s,
            dob=%s,
            address=%s,
        where
            roll_no=%s;
        """ % (
            self.name_var.get(),
            self.email_var.get(),
            self.gender_var.get(),
            self.contact_var.get(),
            self.dob_var.get(),
            self.txt_Address.get('1.0', END),
            self.Roll_No_var.get(),
        ), )
    con.commit()
    con.close()
    self.fetch_data()
    self.clear()
```

Comment: perhaps this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3517090/inserting-an-email-address-into-a-table-field

Comment: That is NOT how you supply parameters to a database call (although don't know the proper way for MySQL offhand).  Using Python's string formatting means that every character entered by the user goes directly into the SQL statement, whether or not it might need quoting; entering `; drop table students` in any field would wipe out your database, for example.

Comment: try splitting the statement and the values to two variables and do parameter substution like `cur.execute(sql_command,values)`

Comment: Change `cur.execute("..." % (...))` to `cur.execute("...", (...))`.

Comment: Thank for your time and support. I resolve it. I made a mistake in , before the where statement.  I will update the variable part since it will prevent some future problem.